# Proving a property theorem on $GA_{n}(\mathbb{F})$

Tags: group-theory

Let $GA_n(\mathbb{F})$ be the group of invertible affine maps on the
vector space $\mathbb{F}^n$.

I'm trying to prove that the order of $T_{A,v}$ is $s$ if and only if $A^s=I$ and $v\in Ker\left(\sum_{m=0}^{s-1}A^{m}\right)$. I have no idea where to start and how to prove this theorem. If that helps, on previous subquestions, I have disproved that $GA_n(\mathbb{F})$ is abelian and I showed that for every $v\in \mathbb{F}^n$, $T_{A,v}^{-1}=T_{A^{-1},w}$ for some $w\in \mathbb{F}^n$.

How should I prove this theorem?

Comment: One direction is easier than the other.  Can you prove this direction?

Comment: @Randall I'm stuck on proving for the $|T_{A,v}|=s$  case. How should I approach it?

Answer (score 0):

Let $T: \mathbb{F}^n \to \mathbb{F}^n$ be an (invertible) affine map, so that $T(x)=Ax+v$ where $A$ is a fixed invertible $n \times n$ matrix over $\mathbb{F}$ and $v$ is a fixed vector in $\mathbb{F}^n$.  (I am not using all the subscript decoration because we don't need them now.)  The key to your problem is to work out the formula for the $k$th iterate $T^k$ of $T$ (we're under composition, of course).

It's not hard.  Note that $T^2$ is given by
$$
T^2(x) = T(T(x)) = A(Ax+v) + v= A^2x + Av +v = A^2x + (A+I)v.
$$
There is a definite pattern here.  Work out $T^3$ if you don't see it.  At any rate, you can prove by induction (or just believe it) that
$$
T^k(x) = A^kx + \sum_{j=0}^{k-1}A^jv.
$$
(Here, $A^0$ is shorthand for the identity.)  This formula gets you both directions of your proof.  The direction $\Leftarrow$ is easy.  For the other direction, how can $T^k$ be the identity transformation?  It has to be that $A^k(x)=x$ for all $x$ and the constant term $\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}A^jv$ must vanish, all simultaneously.  This says that $A^k=I$ and $v$ is in the kernel of $\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}A^j$.  The smallest positive $k$ for which this happens is the order of $T$, and that's what you wished to prove.